# Can you get element.text() from the from an ngBind expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a big long dumb directive using `ngBindTemplate` to accomplish this but if I could simply access the `element.text()` inside the expression I could essentially remove the directive.

**Question:**  How do I access `'element.text()'` from the `ngBind` expression?

```
<h1 ng-bind="worldMapCtrl.header.docs.intro || 'element.text()'">ABC</h1>
```

Comment: can you describe what it is you are trying to accomplish here? it feels like there is something missing.  It wouldn't make sense to write `ng-bind` in an element that already has text; the text is just going to be replaced. And the element text is going to be identical to the value of the variable passed to `ng-bind`. If you are trying to get `ABC` *before* it is replaced by the bind, that feels like a design flaw.

Comment: Ahh I know this has some strong code smell but it has a weird business need. Long story short: All html files go through a compiler where strings are used by a localization team. It's hard to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you can do it, sorry!

Did a test an was unable to access the element it self. If you do:

```
<h1 id="test" ng-bind="worldMapCtrl.header.docs.intro || this.$id">ABC</h1>
```

And then from the console do:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('test')).scope()
```

And check the $id you will see that they are the same. Also if you do:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('test'))
```

You will see that the innerHTML is blank even if the ng-bind failed.

Answer (score 0):

I made a not that long directive, that solves what you want, in case you still want to use a directive, let me know if this work for you.

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('dumbDirective', [function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        htmlInput: '='
      },
      controller: SiteMenuController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true,
      templateUrl: 'dumb-directive-template.html'
    };

    function SiteMenuController() {
      this.text = angular.element(this.htmlInput).text();
    }
  }])

  .run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('dumb-directive-template.html',
      '{{ vm.text }}'
    );
  }]);

})(window.angular);
```

Directive usage:

```
// outputs just 'testing'
<dumb-directive html-input="'<span>testing</span>'"></dumb-directive>
```